# Match integers to letters in Python

Tags: python

I have a string of integers like '32102739' and a dictionary like {32: 'a', '739': 'b', '102': 'c'}. Given that string, I want to return the output string 'acb'.

I am trying

```
def change(string_, letters, length=1):

    if string_[:length] in letters:
        return letters[string_[:length]]
    else:
        return change(string_, letters, length+1)
```

I am having trouble with checking until the first letter is found, and then continuing to check for the next letter.

Comment: Can there be overlap in your keys? For example `32` and `320` or `132`?

Comment: @Cleb Yes, but it won't be ambiguous, like like {'1': 'a', '11': 'b'} and a string '11' which could be 'aa' or 'b'.

Comment: How unambiguous is it? Do you mean that there's only one valid mapping from the whole string, or is there some algorithm that will correctly break any ambiguity immediately when you come to it (e.g. the longest matching key is always the right one)? Consider translating `"12345"` with the dictionary `{1:'a', 12:'b', 23:'c', 34:'d', 45:'e'}`. It's unambiguous if you have to translate the whole input string, but you can't solve it greedily. Without the 5 at the end you'd need to pick a different first character.

Comment: @Blckknght There will be only one valid mapping from the whole string.

Comment: Then I think you need a more sophisticated algorithm. If the mapping doesn't ensure that a greedy algorithm can work, you can get into trouble. Consider `"1234"` with the dictionary in my earlier comment. If you pick `'a'` for the first number, you'll have a number left unmatched at the end. The code needs to be clever enough to backtrack to also try matching `12` in that situation. Your current algorithm won't do that.

Comment: @Blckknght It only has to try matching 12 if 34 is a key and 234 isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no ambiguity (and that the numbers don't overlap), one could proceed as:

```
s = '32102739'
d = {'32': 'a', '739': 'b', '102': 'c'}

ret = ''

#start at the beginning of the string
pos, N = 0, len(s)

while pos < N:
    #start at the current position pos and keep
    #adding characters until a match is found

    found = False
    for i in range(pos+1, N+1):
        #t = int(s[pos:i])
        t = s[pos:i]
        if t in d:
            ret += d[t]
            found = True
            break

    #if no match is found, signal an "invalid" input
    if not found: raise ValueError

    #update current position in the string
    pos = i

print(ret) #gives 'acb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could work with just a few minor tweaks (at least, it will work for non-overlapping dictionary keys). You just need to change your successful match case so that you recurse on the rest of the string, after translating a prefix. You'll also need to add a base case, so that the recursion stops when the matching fails, or there's nothing left to match.

```
def change(string_, letters, length=1):
    if len(string_) < length:  # base case
        return "" # you might want to test if string_ is empty and if not, raise an exception
    elif string_[:length] in letters:
        return letters[string_[:length]] + change(string_[length:], letters) # add recursion
    else:
        return change(string_, letters, length+1)
```

I'll end with a note that recursion is not as efficient in Python as it is in some other languages. You could restructure your function to use iteration instead of recursion, and it would probably be more efficient and "Pythonic". [ewcz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42878603/1405065) is a good example of such a restructuring.